# MYSQL, How to combine the first 2 letters of the first name and the first 5 letters of the last name

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, concatenation

I'm trying to write an SQL query (using the SELECT function) that will take the first two letters of the first name and the first 5 letters of the last name, then combine them and put them in a new column called "User Name." I've tried using the SUBSTRING and CONCAT functions together, but my syntax isn't right. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: please show your code here

Comment: SELECT LEFT(first_name, 2) AS 'a', SUBSTRING(last_name,1,5) AS 'b'
CONCAT(a,b) AS 'User Name' 
FROM customer_contacts;

Comment: Funnily enough, if you do that with my name, you end up where you started!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use both [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr):

```
select 
  concat(substring(fname, 1, 2), substring(lname, 1, 5)) UserName
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e49e1/1).

Or you can use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) with `CONCAT()`:

```
select 
  concat(left(fname, 2), left(lname, 5)) UserName
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e49e1/2)

If your sample data is:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (`fname` varchar(4), `lname` varchar(50)) ;

INSERT INTO yourtable (`fname`, `lname`)
VALUES ('John', 'Smithton'),
    ('Abby', 'Jonesing');
```

Both queries will return:

```
| USERNAME |
------------
|  JoSmith |
|  AbJones |
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, you can use something like

`select concat(substr(fname,1,3), substr(lname,1,3)) as username from <table_name>;`

Note that u can use substr to trim integer datatypes too, while left() might only work for varchar.

Comment: The original question is about MySQL

Answer (score -1):

Try the below query

```
select first_name,
       substr(first_name,1,2)||substr(lower(last_name),1,5) as "USER NAME",
       last_name 
from employees;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below lines

```
select  concat(left(empfname, 2) + ' ',left(emplname, 2)) UserNamefrom employee
```